# @font-face HattoriHanzoLight does not work

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I downloaded the font from this site:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Hattori-Hanzo

Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'HattoriHanzoLight';
    src: url('hattori_hanzo.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style='font-family: HattoriHanzoLight; font-size: 19px;'>
content
</body>
```

My html file and my font file are in the same directory.

Why do I still see the default font?

Comment: Where did you put the otf file? What browser are you using?

Comment: the font is in the same directory of my test.html file and i am using firefox 8 windows 7

Comment: Does the font-family have to maintain the quotes?

Comment: Is the font file in the correct directory? What browser are you using? Some browsers only accept certain font formats

Comment: @bozdoz: It doesn't if the family name consists of one word without spaces.

Comment: @BoltClock♦ beat me to all my questions!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code is working for me so the only way this won't work is because you either have;

- the file permission is not correct
- the file (from the archive is capitalize and not in your code is not)
- you copy and paste from a source that has an [invisible character](http://www.worldstart.com/the-invisible-character/)

Comment: it was easy, i got the same issue when i copied from outlook code someone sent me